# tap event in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-checkbox

```
<div data-role="header" class="page-header"><h2>Header</h2></div>
<div data-role="content">
    <form>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>Legend:</legend>
            <input name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" type="checkbox"/ >
            <label for="checkbox-1a">Label</label>
```

And I use this script:

```
 $( ".class").on( 'tap', tapHandler ); 
function tapHandler( event ) {
    alert(123);
}
```

When I put this to header `$(".page-header").on('tap'` works great, but when `$("input").on('tap')` nothing happens

Why?
onclick on `input` dont work on mobile devices

Comment: try `vclick` instead of `tap`. `$(document).on('vclick', '.selector', function () { code here });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand, you are not taping on a checkbox input, you are taping on a jQuery Mobile representation of that checkbox. Original in put is hidden.

This will work:

```
$(document).on('tap', '.ui-checkbox', function(){ 
    // Do something    
});
```

Comment: I know this, I've tried your code, but still doesn't work
When I'm changing `'.ui-checkbox'` works great, 
but in `<fieldset>` tap event doesn't work
why?

Comment: What platform are you using for the test?

Comment: Firefox on MacOS, Chrome on iOS

Problem was in event.
I'm changed `tap` event to `change` event, and works great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that jQuery Mobile events cannot be defined in tags, so try to refeer by his id

use `$("#checkbox-1a").on` instead

Comment: I've tried!
and used `bind` instead of `on`. nothing. The problem was into form, i think so